# Unable to interact with my Flutter app to find elements location on Appium inspector 2023.12.2 with Appium 2.4.1

Tags: flutter, appium, driver, appium-inspector, appium-flutter

does anyone know what could be wrong with my flutter driver? I am not able to load my app on the Appium inspector itself so that i am able to locate elements or simply interact with the app?

After starting up the Appium session and adding some capabilities, this is what i am getting:
[The interactive mode app is not loaded into Appium inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIlVc.png)
My capabilities are as follows:

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "Nexus 6 API 34",
  "appium:automationName": "Flutter",
  "appium:app": "Where/my/app/is/stored/on/my/local/machine",
  "platformName": "Android"
}
```

Please see the logs bellow:

```
[logs image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yHqe.jpg)
[Logs imge 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48uAR.jpg)
[log image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ro3.png)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you specifically want to work with flutter native elements(Widgets), you should use the [flutter inspector](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector) instead appium inspector, otherwise you need to use **UIAutomator2** and native context

```
{
  "appium:appPackage": "ua.test.app",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "25877ece",
  "appium:appActivity": "ua.test.app.MainActivity",
  "appium:platformVersion": "10",
  "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  ideally, this could work for android platforms. However, the following worked for me provided that the enableFlutterDriverExtenstion() method is added onto the source code of my debug application:

{
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 15",
  "appium:PlatformVersion": "17.2",
  "appium:automationName": "Xcuitest",
  "appium:app": "/Users/musername/Desktop/Runner.app",
  "platformName": "ios"
}